# How perform an IN() like operation when you need a pair of fields to both match?

Tags: mysql

I have a web (intranet) tool that parses a users list into an array of first and last names.   I'm then looping through that array (which could be 50 times) like:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE last_name = array[x].last AND first_name = array[x].first
```

Is it possible to somehow query all those first/last name combinations at the same time like an `IN` statement with two properties.

What I'd love if it was possible is a single query that returned a record set of every match that was found (I guess like an IN statement w/ 2 properties).  I'm not that great with MySQL but my guess would be this would be something like having a sub-query gather a list of any first name matches and then another sub-query gathering any last name matches.

You know actually if I just made there query as `where first_name IN () OR last_name in ()` I'd have a result set with any possible match and then I could loop through that result set doing a final check for where the first and last names both match.   This db is fast, but it's massive.   For example, there are 8,000+ users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a nice trick with MySQL [row constructors](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/row-subqueries.html):

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    first VARCHAR(50),
    last Varchar(50)
);

INSERT INTO users (first, last) VALUES
('Bill', 'Gates'), ('Steve', 'Jobs'), ('Jon', 'Skeet');

SELECT *
  FROM users
 WHERE (first, last) = ('Bill', 'Gates')
    OR (first, last) = ('Steve', 'Jobs')
    OR (first, last) = ('Jon', 'Skeet');
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6ef9a/2

It also works with `IN`:

```
SELECT *
  FROM users
 WHERE (first, last) IN(
   ('Bill', 'Gates'), ('Steve', 'Jobs'), ('Jon', 'Skeet')
);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6ef9a/6

Answer (score 0):

You can [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/union.html) a bunch of individual SQL queries together and get one result set.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE last_name = array[0].last AND array[0].first = first_name
    UNION
SELECT * FROM users WHERE last_name = array[1].last AND array[1].first = first_name
    UNION
SELECT * FROM users WHERE last_name = array[2].last AND array[2].first = first_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You could concat the name first and then use IN clause.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE CONCAT_WS('|', last_name, first_name) IN (...);
```

Comment: If you do this, the query engine cannot use an index. You'll get a full table scan every time.

Answer (score 0):

8000 records is not "massive" for modern databases... it's "tiny".  That said, if your current solution isn't performing fast enough for you (you did measure the performance and found it unacceptable before asking this, right?), the "correct" solution is as follows:

1. Add a `nameKey` column (string) to the table
2. Write a trigger to populate it on insert and update with "lastName|firstName"; that is, the concatenation of the last name, a delimiter that won't occur in the data, and the first name.
3. Create an index on it
4. When searching, provide the concatenated "lastName|firstName" keys in the `IN()` clause.